# How to grant GCP service account write to a specific Cloud Logging

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-logging, google-iamconditio

I want to grant a GCP service account to submit logs to a specific Cloud Logging stream, or whatever.

Because if I just grant the SA with `roles/logging.logWriter`, the SA might submit logs to an unintended Cloud Logging stream, which is used by other SAs.

```
resource.type="global"
log_name="projects/my-dev-project/logs/my-service"
```

```terraform
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "my-service"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "log_writer" {
  project = "my-dev-project
  role    = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  member  = google_service_account.service_account.member

  condition {
    title       = "Allow write to specific log"
    expression  = "????" # <--- HERE
    # Want to grant to log_name="projects/my-dev-project/logs/my-service"
  }
}
```

I tried below, but did not work

```terraform
expression = "resource.log_name == \"projects/my-dev-project/logs/my-service\""`
```

Answer (score 0):

```terraform
expression = "resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/my-dev-project/logs/my-service\")"
```

With this `expression`,

- The SA can submit logs to `projects/my-dev-project/logs/my-service`
- And logging exceptions will occur when the SA tries to submit logs to the wrong places.

  - Error might look like this: `ERROR: onFailure exception: com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).` on google-cloud-logging-logback. It requires `<log>my-service</log>` in `<appender>`.